# Show preview to side automatically in Visual Studio Code when opening a markdown file

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code to edit markdown file. However, every time I open a markdown file, I need to use the shortcut "ctrl+k v" to show preview to side, which is annoying.

Here is my question. Is there any way that I can have the preview to side right after I open a markdown file?

I am thinking adding a task might be able to implement something like this. But, I am not familiar with task in VS Code at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Installing "Auto-Open Markdown Preview" Plugin can solve this problem. Just click "Extensions", or use shortcut "Ctrl+Shift+X". Type in "Auto-Open Markdown Preview" to search for the extension. Install the extension, and restart your VS Code.